# prevent bootstrap tooltip from hiding on click over it

Tags: jquery, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to prevent the tooltip from hiding when i click over it. except that wherever i click on body it should hide it.

Tooltip should work even on tabbing.

**js fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/C5GBU/41/**

**html:**

```
<div class="bs-example tooltip-demo">
    <div class="bs-example-tooltips">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title=""/>    
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title=""/>     
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-original-title="" title=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({trigger:"focus"});

$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
        //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });                
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

May I suggest triggering the popover `manually`

```
var close = true;
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({trigger:"manual"});

$(document).on('mousedown', function (e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass('popover-content'))
        close = false;
    else
        close = true; 
});

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("blur",function(){
    if(close)
        $(this).popover('hide');
    else 
       $(this).focus();
});

$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("focus",function(){
   if(close)
       $(this).popover('show'); 
});
```

Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/C5GBU/46/)

**Update fix for the tabbing issue:**

Change the `.blur` function to the following:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on("blur",function(){
    if(close)
        $(this).popover('hide');
    else {
       $(this).focus();
       close = true;
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/C5GBU/50/)

Comment: once it is shown its not getting hidden even if click on body..this is happening on the last tooltip

Comment: @susheel What browser are you using?  Works perfectly for me in Chrome

Comment: check the last tooltip click on it and then click outside i mean on the body.. i am using chrome though

Comment: Oh on the last tooltip.  That must be because the width of the last tool tip is all the way across the screen I'll look into it.  If you click a different height on the screen it disappears.

Comment: @susheel You need to change `$(body).on('mousedown', function (e)` to `$(document).on('mousedown', function (e)` You were clicking outside the body that is why it was not working.

Comment: why do I see that blinking effect as if its reloading

Comment: It was not completely polished I was just giving you an idea. It was reloading because I was putting the focus on the input again so I was manually reloading.  I fixed it in my latest update.  http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/C5GBU/46/

Comment: I found an issue. if we click on the tooltip and then use tab its not working ??

Comment: I really like this solution. Any idea why you are not able to highlight the text in the popover once it is shown?  Removing the $(this).focus() from the blur event allows the text to be highlighted, but breaks the overall functionality.  Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game, but I was able to solve this problem after trying other answers:

**HTML:**

```
<a data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" tabindex="0" data-html="true" data-title="my title <button class='close'>×</button>" data-content="my content">
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* not necessary, but makes the x look better, imo */
.popover-title .close {
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-right: -6px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();

// Custom Bootstrap Popover triggers (requires triggers set to manual)
$("body").on("click", function (e) {

    // Trigger toggles associated popover
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("fa-info-circle")) {
        $(e.target).parent().popover("toggle");
    }

    // Popover x closes associated popover
    else if ($(e.target).hasClass("close")) {
        $(e.target).closest(".popover").siblings("[data-toggle='popover']").popover("hide");
    }

    // Everything else closes all popovers
    else if (!$(e.target).closest(".popover").length) {
        $(".popover").siblings("[data-toggle='popover']").popover("hide");
    }
});
```

- Clicking an information icon toggles the associated popover.
- Clicking a popover x closes the associated popover.
- Clicking anywhere else closes all popovers.
- Multiple popovers can be open at once.
- HTML can be used inside popover body as well.
- Popovers can be added/removed and handler will still work.

Comment: @thefreeline, this was a result of the same problem you were having with the accepted answer, which I tried as well, where the html content wasn't highlighting, etc.