# Prevent tooltip from hiding when clicked, by tweaking events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script running on Twitter, and I created tooltips by replicating the behaviour of them. I mean, a basic tooltip in Twitter needs a class `js-tooltip` and a `data-original-title` attribute. When the mouse is over the element, the class `in` is added to the element.

This is my injected element,

```
<a class="custom js-tooltip" data-original-title="My message" href="#"><img src="icon.png"/></a>
```

And this is my content script,

```
$('body').on('click', '.custom', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var elem = $(e.target);
    var a = elem.parent();

    a.attr('data-original-title', 'clicked');
    // forcing mouseenter did nothing
    elem.trigger('mouseenter')
}
```

Is there any way to prevent tooltip from hiding when clicked?

Comment: Probably duplicate with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414901/prevent-bootstrap-tooltip-from-hiding-on-click-over-it

Comment: I'm not using any tooltip library. I've added `js-tooltip` class to my element in order to make Twitter magically transform that into a tooltip. I have no control over the tooltip library.

Comment: If you don't want to use any jQuery plugin, follow up this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153882/how-to-make-tooltip-with-pure-javascript-onclick-show-dismiss

Comment: I wasn't using any plugin. I'm using what Twitter is using, just adding the `js-tooltip` class. It works. However I can't control over this issue. Is there any workaround?